# Bulkify Lead industry recategorization

Tags: salesforce, apex, force.com

I am trying to setup a job that I can run couple times a day to keep our leads categorized to meet our sales and Marketing approved list. My tests scripts work great. However, when I go to run it in my sandbox I am running with a bunch of dummy data I am running into issues with DML limits.

I am looking for ideas how I can process as many leads as possible efficiently.

Edit:

> 18:00:20.106 (10106660336)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[377]|System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151
> 18:00:20.106 (10106789908)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151
>
> Number of DML statements: 151 out of 150 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
> Number of DML rows: 150 out of 10000

```apex
global class Industry_Mappings Implements Schedulable {
    Public List < Lead > DisplayIndLeads;
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

        DisplayIndLeads = new List < Lead > ();
        DisplayIndLeads = [select Industry, Sub_Industry__c from Lead where Sub_Industry__c = null and Industry < > Null and IsConverted < > True];

        //This will create a little efficenty with the for loops
        Integer skip = 0;
        Integer i = 0;

        //Advertising and Marketing
        List < string > AdvertisingAndMarketing = new List < string > {
            'Design', 'Graphic Design', 'Market Research'
        };


        //List for looping
        List < lead > leadstoupdate = new List < Lead > {};

        //This starts the Loop for the leads
        for (Lead ld : DisplayIndLeads) {
            //lead l = (Lead)ld;
            //leadstoupdate.size();

            //Advertising and Marketing
            if (skip == 0) {
                for (string AnM : AdvertisingAndMarketing) {
                    if (ld.Industry == AnM) {
                        ld.Sub_Industry__c = ld.Industry;
                        ld.Industry = 'Advertising and Marketing';
                        skip = 99;
                        leadstoupdate.add(ld);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.debug('***** What is in leadstoupdate: ' + leadstoupdate);
            update leadstoupdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the error which you got

Comment: 18:00:20.106 (10106660336)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[377]|System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151
18:00:20.106 (10106789908)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151

  Number of DML statements: 151 out of 150 ******* CLOSE TO LIMIT
  Number of DML rows: 150 out of 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using DML operation inside the `for` loop what leads to the error.
You just need to mode the DML statement outside the `for` loop

```apex
    for (Lead ld : DisplayIndLeads) {
        if (skip == 0) {
            for (string AnM : AdvertisingAndMarketing) {
                if (ld.Industry == AnM) {
                    ld.Sub_Industry__c = ld.Industry;
                    ld.Industry = 'Advertising and Marketing';
                    skip = 99;
                    leadstoupdate.add(ld);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    update leadstoupdate;
```

**- - - - UPDATE - - - -**

The reason why your code updated just one lead is the fact that you have a condition `if (skip == 0)` which false (because you set it to 99) after adding first Lead to `leadsToUpdate` list.

Change this condition or even remove it because I do not see any reasons for that.

```apex
    for (Lead ld : DisplayIndLeads) {
        for (string AnM : AdvertisingAndMarketing) {
            if (ld.Industry == AnM) {
                ld.Sub_Industry__c = ld.Industry;
                ld.Industry = 'Advertising and Marketing';
                leadstoupdate.add(ld);
            }
        }
    }
    update leadstoupdate;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did move that outside of the forloop in a different attempts. The issue I had with that is that it only seemed to update the last record in the list from the for loop.  So the leadstoupdate seemed to get overwritten every time the scrip looped though. Any idea on a way to work around that issue?

Comment: I moved the update out of the loop and run the script again and it pushes though the leads but it only updates one lead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I removed the if statement and that fixed the issue. The reason I had it in there is that section is part of a larger script with several different lead types. I added it to try to add a little efficiency to the script by if the record matched then skip all the other for loop evaluations. I was concerned about CPU time caps.